# Can this be converted to stream one-liner?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am wondering if this could be written more neatly as a stream function:

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject();

for (Thing thing : listofThings) {
    myObject = myObject.combine(thing);
}
```

Comment: What you've tried already?

Comment: And what does your `MyObject` class look like?

Comment: you are aware that you are for each thing in the list overwriting your "myObject". so when the loop is finished you will only have acces to the latest thing. Maybe you should post what "MyObject" consists of..

Comment: Please stop using streams for trivial things. Your loop solution is just fine!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, using a `Stream` with `reduce`:

```
MyObject myObject = listofThings.stream()
                                .reduce(new MyObject(),
                                        MyObject::combine,
                                        MyObject::combiner);
```

where `combiner` is a `MyObject` method that takes another `MyObject` instance and combines it into the current object.

As an alternative, you can first `map` the `Thing` instances to `MyObject` instances, and then reduce these instances to a single `MyObject` instance:

```
MyObject myObject = listofThings.stream()
                                .map(new MyObject()::combine)
                                .reduce(MyObject::combiner)
                                .orElseGet(MyObject::new);
```

Comment: `MyObject::combiner` will be used only in parallel stream, so it can just throw exception.

Comment: You can explicitly make it even simplier by combining map with reduce.

Comment: @MS90 not sure it's simpler with map+reduce. Please set edit to answer.

Comment: ok, this works, but I wouldnt really call that written more nicely than the loop variant ;)

Comment: @Georg true, but it does answer the question in the title - `Can this be converted to stream one-liner?`